# How can I identify an std::function in a container and remove it?

Tags: c++, std-function

I currently have an `std::vector` of `std::function` that represents a collection of listeners in an Observer-like pattern. `std::function` has been chosen so that any type of listener can be subscribed, such as function pointers, lambdas or class functors.

That said, I would like to unsubscribe a listener, but I realized that `std::function` does not define `operator==` between two `std::function` objects.

Any idea? Code can be entirely changed.

Comment: Use an ID for each listener.

Comment: @ThomasSablik and return the id to the subscriber so that it can delete itself when needed?

Comment: I find your question clearly stated, but I think that adding a MCVE would be helpful for solution proposals!

Comment: Yes, that's the way it is done in many frameworks.

Comment: How would you identify a lambda that you wanted to unsubscribe? Lambda's are unique; even their type is.

Comment: @ThomasSablik what is your opinion on using an `std::list` instead of an `std::vector` to collect the callbacks, and return an iterator handler to the subscriber instead of defining ids?

Comment: I think, that should work, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an ID for each listener.

```
using ID = int;

ID listener1 = subject.subscribe([](){/* some code */});

/* some more code */

subject.unsubscribe(listener1);
```

Alternatively you can use a class for subscriptions than can unsubscribe itself. It contains the ID and the subject.

```
class Subscription {
    ID id;
    Subject subject;

public:
    Subscription(ID id, Subject subject) : id(id), subject(subject) {}
    void unsubscribe() {
        subject.unsubscribe(id);
    }
};

Subscription listener1 = subject.subscribe([](){/* some code */});

/* some more code */

listener1.unsubscribe();
```